# Retrieve Dicom image from Pacs server

Tags: java, dicom

I am Querying / retrieving dicom image from remote Pacs server using DcmQR , i able to get list of Dicom objects by specified criteria.
1. when writing dicom object its showing 1 kb in size only.
2. When print object data its printing each data null.
I am very new in this please help me out .. :(

```
     My code :

    public static void main(String args[]){

    dcmqr = new DcmQR("DCM4CHEE");
    dcmqr.setCalledAET("DCM4CHEE", true);
    dcmqr.setRemoteHost("remote ip");
    dcmqr.setRemotePort(remote port);
    dcmqr.getKeys();
    dcmqr.setDateTimeMatching(true);
    dcmqr.setCFind(true);
    dcmqr.setCGet(true);


    dcmqr.setQueryLevel(DcmQR.QueryRetrieveLevel.IMAGE);
    dcmqr.addMatchingKey(Tag.toTagPath("PatientName"),"Vicens^DICOM");
    dcmqr.configureTransferCapability(true);

    List<DicomObject> result = null;    
    try {
    dcmqr.start();
    dcmqr.open();
    result = dcmqr.query();
    dcmqr.get(result);
    System.out.println("List Size : " + result.size());
    displayObjectDetails(result);
    for (DicomObject dco : result) {
               Byte data[] = toByteArray(dco);

               // here how can get dicom image ??


    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error " + e);
    }
    try {
      if (dcmqr != null) {
        dcmqr.stop();
        dcmqr.close();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

// toByteArray Method here 
private static byte[] toByteArray(DicomObject obj) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(baos);
        DicomOutputStream dos = new DicomOutputStream(bos);
        dos.writeDicomFile(obj);
        dos.close();          
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();  
        return data;
}

// display object details
```

private static void displayObjectDetails(List resultimg) {

```
DicomObject obj = new BasicDicomObject();
List<String> listimg = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < resultimg.size(); i++) {
    obj = resultimg.get(i);

    System.out.println("InstanceNumber : "+obj.getString(Tag.InstanceNumber, VR.IS));
    System.out.println("ImageType : "+obj.getString(Tag.ImageType, VR.CS));
    System.out.println("ImageID : "+obj.getString(Tag.ImageID, VR.SH));
    System.out.println("RetrieveAETitle : "+obj.getString(Tag.RetrieveAETitle, VR.AE));
    System.out.println("SOPInstanceUID : "+obj.getString(Tag.SOPInstanceUID, VR.UI));

    System.out.println("PatientName : "+obj.getString(Tag.PatientName, VR.PN));
    System.out.println("PatientBirthDate : "+obj.getString(Tag.PatientBirthDate, VR.DA));
    System.out.println("PatientSex : "+obj.getString(Tag.PatientSex, VR.CS));
    System.out.println("ReferringPhysicianName : "+obj.getString(Tag.ReferringPhysicianName, VR.PN));
    System.out.println("StudyDescription : "+obj.getString(Tag.StudyDescription, VR.LO));
    System.out.println("SeriesDescription : "+obj.getString(Tag.SeriesDescription, VR.LO));

    }
```

// Output 
List Size = 8
InstanceNumber : 1
ImageType : null
ImageType : null
RetrieveAETitle : DCM4CHEE
SOPInstanceUID : 1.3.12.2.1107.5.2.5.11090.5.0.582504825601085
PatientName : null
PatientBirthDate : null
PatientSex : null
ReferringPhysicianName : null
StudyDescription : null
SeriesDescription : null

Comment: Or can i write / store dicom image on my local system???

Comment: Try removing the `dcmqr.setCFind(true);` part, using only the CGet.

Comment: Hi Gilberto, Very Very thanks for your reply. I commented dcmdr.setCFind(true); but output is same every thing is null.

Comment: When i tried to getBufferedIamge AS : 
bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(dicomData);
iter = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("DICOM");
reader = (ImageReader) iter.next();
param =reader.getDefaultReadParam(); 
ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(bais);
reader.setInput(iis, false); 
bufferImage = reader.read(0, param); 

} Its giving java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at Line  //bufferImage = reader.read(0, param);  Please help

Comment: You have to also indicate all the tags you want returned. By default, you will only get values back matching the criteria you provided. It is curious that PatientName is null in the response. This may indicate a strange implementation of the c-find scp.

Comment: Hi Brett, Thanks for reply. This is all code that i have done to get DICOM image from remote server, i have not implement c-find myself, i have imported all the DCM4CHEE dependencies. Is anything else i have to do to get proper dicom object from pacs server??

Comment: I am not much interested in patient name and anything i interested in only DICOM image that i have to convert in JPE and store on my local server so that iPhone client can access them and display.

Comment: Have you read the dcmqr usage text? It covers the issues with c-get (as opposed to c-move). It also shows the arguments you need to provide at command line to get c-get to work. Take a look at the source and copy its behavior with those command line options. http://www.dcm4che.org/confluence/download/attachments/438/dcmqr+usage.txt?version=1&modificationDate=1351401060265  https://svn.code.sf.net/p/dcm4che/svn/dcm4che2/trunk/dcm4che-tool/dcm4che-tool-dcmqr/src/main/java/org/dcm4che2/tool/dcmqr/DcmQR.java

Comment: Thanks Brett, I have read dcmqr usage and run the command line in dos, its received matching entry displaying on console but din't write anything in out put folder. May you suggest dcmqr text that has complete procedure?, And i ll go through link you have provided and revert.

Comment: The cli example given in the doc is "dcmqr  -L DCMQR  DCM4CHEE@RadiologyServer:11112  -q00100020=QCTEST1 -q00100021=JHH  -cget -cstore 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.128 -cstoredest C:\Test" What command did you use? Do you know the sop class uids of the objects you want to retrieve?

Comment: Yes i am using sop class UID to retrieve but din't get anything in destination folder. I use command dcmqr  -L DCMQR:11113  DCM4CHEE@Remote Ip:11112  -cmove DCMQR -cstore 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.2  -cstoredest C:\Test , How can i send you log file, is there any way? so that you easily understand whats wrong going on.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you are only saving the query response? There are two ways to retrieve images from PACS, one is to send C-MOVE with the move destination AE set as your DICOM listener’s AE.  The second way, although it is not very common, is to send a C-GET request.

Comment: Hi LEADTOOLS, Thanks for reply. i already done it and working well using c-move.